# Rails - form_tag sending with wrong verb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a form that I'm trying to use to send get requests, however it will only send patch. I've read through the documentation and various answers on stack overflow that seem to address my issue but still can't solve it..

```
<%= form_tag(edit_content_page_dynamic_panel_path(
             parent_page,
             dynamic_panel),
             method: :get,
             available_condition: params[:available_condition]) %>
<p>
<%= text_field_tag :available_condition, params[:avaialble_condition] %>
<%= button_tag "Search", :name => nil, method: :get %>
```

I've tried placing the method: :get outside of the brackets as well as rearranging the arguments to no avail. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Can you show us your `routes.rb`?

Comment: What does the generated HTML look like?

Comment: Started PATCH "/content-hub/pages/6544/panels/4460" for ::1 at 2017-02-08 11:50:49 +0000
Processing by DynamicPanelsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"GfOBsowBEBAq/w4AMTAG0oTGZqbT8ZPcrgn1ofzaAa6w+pJWJtukwJVgjHprKCuor1tEpee7Atbpy9WTRYG+Qw==", "dynamic_panel"=>{"title"=>"bla 2"}, "associated_condition"=>"winner", "content_page_id"=>"6544", "dynamic_panel_id"=>"4460"}

Answer (score 0):

Was trying for an hour and as soon as I posted I managed it via trial and error..

```
<%= form_tag(edit_content_page_dynamic_panel_path(
             parent_page,
             dynamic_panel),
             method: :get) do %>
<p>
<%= text_field_tag :available_condition, params[:avaialble_condition] %>
<%= submit_tag "Search" %>
```

I believe it was the extra param in the form_tag method that was causing the issue.